# StreamReader C# - read only a specific line

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to log only 3rd line (or lines 1 to 3 if logging just one line is not possible) from a webResposne.

here is a snippet of the code that I am using for now.

```
StreamReader read = new StreamReader(myHttpWebResponse.GetResponseStream(), System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);
        String result = read.ReadToEnd();
        Log("Access", Server.HtmlEncode(result), "Success");
```

I am getting the following output

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Access is Granted.</title>
    <style>
     body {font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:normal;font-size: .7em;color:black;} 
     p {font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:normal;color:black;margin-top: -5px}
     b {font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:bold;color:black;margin-top: -5px}
     H1 { font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:normal;font-size:18pt;color:red }
     H2 { font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:normal;font-size:14pt;color:maroon }
...
```

and so on.

I would just like to log "(title>Access is Granted.(/title>" and not print anything else (or anything after that line).

How would I go about doing that?

Thank you

Comment: Have you tried writing a Regex for your task? If so, are you having issues with it?

Comment: assuming this question is "what is the name of StreamReader.ReadLine method and if it is ok to call it 3 times ignoring result first 2 times" - possible duplicate of [How to skip first line while reading csv using streamreader](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9093223/how-to-skip-first-line-while-reading-csv-using-streamreader) -

Comment: Are you sure you only want line 3 or is it the <title> tag you're going after specifically?

Answer (score 1):

If you need read a specific line instead of using `ReadToEnd` you should look into using [`ReadLine`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader.readline.aspx), then you should be able to count the number of lines read to know when you've gotten to the line(s) you need.

Answer (score 1):

You could read all lines into an array so you can refer to a specific line via index.

Comment: If you read in all lines at once you can use [`File.ReadLines`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383503.aspx), but that won't work with streams, which looks like the OP is reading in.

Comment: If you provide an answer that refers to a method, provide an example of the method like @JGinSD. Not sure if reading all the lines is worth it to get three lines deep in a file.

Answer (score 1):

Build extension method:

```
public static IEnumerable<string> ReadLines(this StreamReader reader)
{
     yield return reader.ReadLine();
}
```

Then you can use LINQ to select any line you want, example below is to select the third line:

```
 var result  = streamReader.ReadLines()
                           .ElementAtOrDefault(2);
```

You still take advantage of *deferred execution* on this way

Comment: You want the line at index 2, and it's easier to do `streamReader.ReadLines().ElementAt(2)`

Comment: Still think you need to change it from 3 to 2 (zero-based indexing).

Answer (score 1):

Regex will do the trick. Simple example:

```
string test = @"<html>\n<head>\n<title>Access is Granted.</title>\n<style>...";
string output = Regex.Match(test, "<title>.*</title>").Value;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [HtmlAgilityPack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/).

Run the response through it and extract the line(s) you need.

Plain and simple

Answer (score 0):

How about using an `XmlReader` to read the exact value you want from the HTML document? Since `XmlReader` is streaming you won't have to bother reading the entire document as with the array method, and it will automatically parse it for you. This is safer than relying on the `<title>` tag being on a certain line.

```
using(var reader = XmlReader.Create(myHttpWebResponse.GetResponseStream()))
{
    reader.ReadToDescendant("title");
    var result = "<title>" + reader.ReadElementString() + "</title>";
    Log("Access", Server.HtmlEncode(result), "Success");
}
```

Comment: `XmlReader` may likely fail trying to read in HTML, as HTML is not necessarily XML

Comment: Yeah, I tested it with the given HTML, seemed to work.  Only the first 3 lines need to be valid XML, since XmlReader parses lazily.