# Import CSV file to Mongo database

Tags: c#, mongodb, csv, import

If I want to import a CSV file from the command line I simply use:

```
mongoimport -d <database> -c <collection name> --type csv --file <path to csv> --headerline
```

Of course `headerline` is optional. In my case, the CSV files do have a header.

How can I do the same via C#? Is there a similar one line command? I know how to [read a CSV file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5283044/283650) but I'm surprised I cannot find (a single?) simple command(s).

I have looked at a lot of the [online documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/getting-started/csharp/) but much of it seems to be for a different .NET driver version; mine is version 2.2.4.

Here is the *long way around* code so far (it works but I'm thinking it can be done more easily):

```
MongoClient client = new MongoClient("mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/test"); // local database
var db = client.GetDatabase("test");

var reader = new StreamReader(File.OpenRead(@"<full path to csv")); // where <full path to csv> is the file path, of course
IMongoCollection<BsonDocument> csvFile = db.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("test");

reader.ReadLine(); // to skip header

while (!reader.EndOfStream)
{
    var line = reader.ReadLine();
    var values = line.Split(',');

        BsonDocument row = new BsonDocument
        {
            {"Column0", values[0]},
            {"Column1", values[1]},
            {"Column2", values[2]},
            {"Column3", values[3]}
        };

    csvFile.InsertOne(row);
}
```

One disadvantage of this format is that I must have exactly four columns - which I cannot guarantee.

The perfect answer will include a way to [skip the header row](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9093253/283650).

<sub>In case it is relevant: I'm looking to import multiple CSV files so I will find each in a directory - [but I know how to do that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/929418/283650).</sub>

Comment: Rather than add the key/value pairs in the BsonDocument constructor you can create a Dictionary<String,Object> containing the pairs, and then add that to the BsonDocument using row.AddRange(dictionary).

Answer (score 2):

I used CSVHelper to read it. PM console -> https://www.nuget.org/packages/CsvHelper/

I've done it in 3 classes :

- Program.cs (Where I read the actual .csv and call for object creating class)
- Products.cs (The collection details and .csv cols must be the same)
- Mongo.cs (Connecting to MongoDB and inserting or updating documents)

Program.cs:

```
using CsvHelper;
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;

namespace DataImport
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // .CSV file path
            Console.WriteLine("Absolute path to .csv file: ");
            string csvFilePath = Console.ReadLine();

            // Reading .csv file line by line and calling for SendingRecord method
            using (var reader = new StreamReader(csvFilePath))
            using (var csv = new CsvReader(reader))
        {
            csv.Configuration.HasHeaderRecord = false; // My file has no header lines, if yours have this must be 'true'
            csv.Configuration.ShouldSkipRecord = record => record.All(string.IsNullOrEmpty); // Skipping empty lines in .CSV file
            var records = csv.GetRecords<Products>().ToList();
            for (int i = 0; i < records.Count; i++)
            {
                Mongo.SendingRecord(records[i]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

That creates List of objects witch can be put separately in mongoDB documents.

Products.cs:

```
using CsvHelper.Configuration;
using CsvHelper.Configuration.Attributes;

namespace DataImport
{
public class Products
{
    [Index(0)]
    public string prop1
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    [Index(1)]
    public decimal prop2
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    [Index(2)]
    public int prop3
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

public class ProductsMap : ClassMap<Products>
{
    public ProductsMap()
    {
        Map(m => m.prop1);
        Map(m => m.prop2);
        Map(m => m.prop3);
    }
}
```

Here you need to specify all rows of the .csv file and map them properly. The indexes represent row in excell (index0 = A, index1 = B ...)

Mongo.cs:

```
using MongoDB.Driver;

namespace DataImport
{
class Mongo
{
    public static void SendingRecord(Products output)
    {
        // Connecting to MongoDB
        string connectionString = "mongodb://localhost:27017";
        MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient(connectionString);

        // Navigating to DB and Collection
        var db = mongoClient.GetDatabase("DB-name");

        var products = db.GetCollection<Products>("Collection-Name");

        // Importing new documents or updating existing ones
        var options = new UpdateOptions();
        options.IsUpsert = true;
        products.ReplaceOne(filter: x => x.uniqueField == output.uniqueField, replacement: output, options: options);
    }
}
```

This is with connection string for localhost. For this to work u need at least one unique value for the records - id, some sort of number, etc.

If u have any questions, don't hesitate. Just ask.

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately, I can no longer verify this solution (I've moved on to a new project). If someone else confirms that this works, I will accept.

Comment: Yeah. I saw it was from 3y ago, but i tried to do this for like 2-3 days and the are no realy usefull docs, so when i managed to do it, i decided to share.

Comment: Great, and you have my +1 for sharing! Hope it helps more people.

Comment: Excellent solution, it's a pity this is not the selected answer

Answer (score 0):

You use that command on the cmd? I suggest you create a .bat file with a `StreamWriter` then execute that .bat File with `Process.Start()`, passing it the filename as a parameter.

Way better: To execute on the commandline use this snippet

```
string command = ""; //enter any command you want
System.Diagnostics.Process process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();
startInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
startInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
startInfo.Arguments = "/C " + command;
process.StartInfo = startInfo;
process.Start();
```

Comment: Indeed, I was considering that as a backup plan. But there must be a way to do it directly in `C#` code, I think?

Comment: Thanks, but I would rather do it directly in the code. I can now but am thinking that there must be a more efficient way...

Answer (score 0):

No need to create an external .bat file. Just run the command using windows process start :-)

Download "MongoDB Command Line Database Tools"-

https://www.mongodb.com/try/download/database-tools

(1) Unzip the file and copy mongoimport.exe and paste it in your project (right-click on the project from solution explorer and paste)

(2) after paste, right-click on the mongoimport.exe file from solution explorer and choose properties.

(3) then change the property value of "Copy to Output Directory" to "Copy always"

(4) follow the bellow code-

```
namespace ConsoleApp1
{
  class Program
  {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
     string command = "--db yourDBName --collection yourCollectionName --type csv --file D:\\yourFileName.csv --headerline"; 
        System.Diagnostics.Process process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
        System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();
        startInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
        startInfo.FileName = "mongoimport.exe";
        startInfo.Arguments =  command;
        process.StartInfo = startInfo;
        process.Start();
      }
    }
}
```